# Pandas 文字列の置換

Tags: python, pandas

次のような、部屋の階数を示すデータがあります。
['2', 'B1', '23-49', 'M2']
B1は地下一階を、23-49は、23階を、M2は不明なので、欠損値にしたいと考えています。

[2, -1, 23, NaN]

しかし、現在は、全てNanになってしまいます。
文字列の置換方法の理解が足りないためと思いますが、
ご教示下さいますとありがたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'kai': ['2', 'B1', '23-49', 'M2']},
    index=[1, 2, 3,4])

df['kai']=df['kai'].replace('23-49', r'(\d)')
df['kai']=df['kai'].str.replace(r'B(\d*)', -\d*)
df['kai']=df['kai'].str.replace(r'M(\d*)', np.nan)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こんな感じでしょうかね？

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'kai': ['2', 'B1', '23-49', 'M2']},
    index=[1, 2, 3, 4])

df['kai'] = df['kai'].replace({
    r'^B(\d+)': r'-\1',
    r'^(\d+)-(\d+)': r'\1',
    r'^M(\d+)': np.nan},
    regex=True).astype('float')

print(df)
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。replace以下の内容で、置換前と置換後の値を、辞書のようにして書けることは知りませんでした。勉強になります。今後ともよろしくお願い致します。